# Is it possible to recover coins after clicking on Reset Options button?

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I use emercoin windows wallet - 
Emercoin Core version v0.6.3emc (64-bit)

I clicked the button - Reset options.
The app restarted, 
and balance changed to 0.
The wallet was completely out of sync after restarting.
But even after syncing all blockchain the balance doesn't change.
The balance equals 0.

My intention was just resetting options to default
but my coins have disappear.

Does it mean that I've completely lost all my coins ?
Or there is a way to restore coins ?

Need help.

I didn't create any backup wallet.

Comment: When asking a question that refers to a specific just interface, please include which application/website it is you are referring to.  Without this critical piece of information, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1355500.0) helps me detect a problem and fix it.

> It looks like you had set a different data directory and resetting the
>   options cleared that setting.